# Inducted charge on a grounded sphere by a square of electric charge

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, induction

Consider a grounded conductive sphere with radius of $a$ surrounded by four lines of charge of $2a$ length and charge density of $D(C/m)$ each.

What will be the inducted charge on the sphere?

I was thinking about solving this with method of image charges but couldn't figure the right image charge.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that is the integral form of the solution for a [point charge at a sphere](http://www.physicspages.com/2011/12/12/method-of-images-point-charge-and-sphere/), as any superposition should work. If you want the total induced charge, I guess it is just the according integral over equation 9 in the link.

Should be something like $-q \ln(1+\sqrt{2})$